# Changing bundle Identifier - Acquired an application to create new version from scratch

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

My company have acquired an app that was already on the app store. The bundle identifier contained the old company name e.g `com.oldcompany.CoolApp`. However we are to build a new app to take its place, can we change its bundle id in iTunesConnect? e.g `com.newcompany.CoolApp`. Can this be done? What are the other possible conflicts?

Although the app is in the hands of a new company, must we continue to use the old Bundle ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, if you match the bundle identifier and app name then there is no problem. The phone views it as the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the app to a different developer account. Check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: Does this allow for a change in Bundle Identifier? It doesn't explicitly say.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You can not change the bundle id, only the app name. You could however delete the app and publish it again in order to set a new bundle id. This implies that it will be a new app for Apple and you must pass the Apple review process again. In addition, if you use push notifications, in app purchases and so on, you will have to generate new certificates for it.